# How to safely use json web tokens from external application that talks to wordpress rest api

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, wordpress, jwt

I have a question related to JWT.
Here is the scenario.

- **A** -> wordpress site with wp rest api enabled;
- **B** -> External application (let's say simple javascript/jQuery app)

So if i want to do a post request/ create a new post on the wordpress website (A), i can do that by providing username + password and then get a JWT token to authenticate. If i set-up a quick login functionality it basically works without the risk of exposing the username and password.
However, the problem is the following:
What if i need the application to let's say fetch all the posts from A (wordpress website through rest api), but i don't want a login functionality, basically i need a way to provide user login credentials to get a jwt token, but that doesn't make sense to me since someone can just inspect the js code and extract that information?

Comment: Do you want to make an api route that is not protected? (Accessible by not logged in users)

Comment: No, sorry if my question wasn't clear.
I want to know how to protect the username and password i provide in the javascript file on the external application used to get a token from the api. Basically if i place the user and password in the javascript file would't someone be just able to inspect my application and collect the username and password thus be able to get an access token and perform malicious activities?

Answer (score 0):

The code to generate a jwt is like this. As you can see, email and name are a onetime variable in the javascript file. The username and email itself are not embedded in the code.

```
userSchema.methods.generateJwt = function() {
  var expiry = new Date();
  expiry.setDate(expiry.getDate() + 7);

  return jwt.sign(
    {
      _id: this._id,
      email: this.email,
      name: this.name,
      exp: parseInt(expiry.getTime() / 1000)
    },
    jwt_secret
  );
};
```

The only thing you may accidently expose is the jwt_secret. For this, you should store the secret inside a [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) file and not commit it to version control.

```
require("dotenv").config();
const jwt_secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
```